# How to generate a filmstrip image in python from a folder of images?

Tags: python, django, image, python-imaging-library

I would like to do the equivalent off [this](http://www.bigdumbdev.com/2007/08/build-better-skimmer-part-2.html) (ruby code) in python for a Django project I am working on. I want to make a [filmstrip image](http://designvigilante.com/files/photoSkim/filmStrip.jpg) of X number of images in a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a function that wraps **the contact sheet** function [S.Lott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10661/slott) mentioned.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, os.path
from contactsheet import make_contact_sheet

def make_film_strip(fnames,
                   (photow,photoh),
                   (marl,mart,marr,marb),
                   padding):
    return make_contact_sheet(fnames,
                              (1, len(fnames)),
                              (photow,photoh),
                              (marl,mart,marr,marb),
                              padding)
```

It is assuming the [recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/412982/) is saved as `contactsheet.py`. Usage is:

```
fstrip = filmstrip.make_film_strip(filmstrip.fnames, (120, 120), (0,0,0,0), 0)
fstrip.save('/path/to/file.format')
```

Tested.

Comment: Thanks, the wrapping is good, thanks but i think i will try to make å decoupled solution, just modify the script and see if i can make it work...

Answer (score 4):

Do you mnean something like this?  [Use PIL to make a "contact sheet" of images](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/412982/)?

Perhaps there are others here that are closer to what you want: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/tags/graphics/

Comment: It's something like this, but this is over complicated, i want a singlecolumn "list" of images, and need the images to be loaded from a folder. I guess it is possible to modify that script to do that.

Comment: My thought is that the row number is always 0.  Based on that, you can simplify this considerably.