# How to complete this python function to save in the same folder?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to write my first real python function that does something real. What i want to accomplish is searching a given folder, and then open all images and merging them together so they make a filmstrip image. Imagine 5 images stacked on top of eachother in one image.

I have this code now, which should be pretty much ok, but propably needs some modification:

```
import os
import Image

def filmstripOfImages():

    imgpath = '/path/here/'
    files = glob.glob(imgpath + '*.jpg')

    imgwidth = files[0].size[0]
    imgheight = files[0].size[1]
    totalheight = imgheight * len(files)

    filename = 'filmstrip.jpg'
    filmstrip_url = imgpath + filename

    # Create the new image. The background doesn't have to be white
    white = (255,255,255)
    filmtripimage = Image.new('RGB',(imgwidth, totalheight),white)  
    row = 0
    for file in files:
        img = Image.open(file)

        left = 0
        right = left + imgwidth
        upper = row*imgheight
        lower = upper + imgheight
        box = (left,upper,right,lower)
        row += 1

        filmstripimage.paste(img, box)
    try:
        filmstripimage.save(filename, 'jpg', quality=90, optimize=1)
    except:
        filmstripimage.save(miniature_filename, 'jpg', quality=90)")
```

How do i modify this so that it saves the new filmstrip.jpg in the same directory as I loaded the images from? And it probably has some things that are missing or wrong, anybody got a clue?

Related question: [How to generate a filmstrip image in python from a folder of images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334827/how-to-generate-a-filmstrip-image-in-python-from-a-folder-of-images)

Comment: you forgot to import glob (or forgot to paste the import statement)

Comment: you forgot to try to run the code at least once

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not an answer to your question, but It might be helpful:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from PIL import Image

def makefilmstrip(images, mode='RGB', color='white'):
    """Return a combined (filmstripped, each on top of the other) image of the images.

    """
    width  = max(img.size[0] for img in images)
    height = sum(img.size[1] for img in images)
    
    image = Image.new(mode, (width, height), color) 
    
    left, upper = 0, 0
    for img in images:
        image.paste(img, (left, upper))
        upper += img.size[1]

    return image

if __name__=='__main__':
    # Here's how it could be used:
    from glob import glob
    from optparse import OptionParser

    # process command-line args
    parser = OptionParser()
    parser.add_option("-o", "--output", dest="file",
                      help="write combined image to OUTPUT")

    options, filepatterns = parser.parse_args()
    outfilename = options.file
    
    filenames = []
    for files in map(glob, filepatterns):
        if files:
            filenames += files

    # construct image
    images = map(Image.open, filenames)    
    img = makefilmstrip(images)
    img.save(outfilename)
```

Example:

```
$ python filmstrip.py -o output.jpg *.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution seems clever, but when i try to implement it, and run the map(Image.open,...) I get an error:

"type object 'Image' has no attribute 'open'"

Any clue to why this is happening?

Comment: @Espen Christensen: Check that `Image = type(Image)` is *NOT* present in your code. Copy-paste my code. What is the result?

Comment: Currently this results in `SystemError: tile cannot extend outside image`. I looked at a couple of answers related to this error, but wasn't able to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you change your `try` section to this:

```
filmstripimage.save(filmstrip_url, 'jpg', quality=90, optimize=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

In the case you are not joking there are several problems with your script e.g. `glob.glob()` returns list of filenames (string objects, not Image objects) therefore `files[0].size[0]` will not work.

Answer (score 1):

as J. F. Sebastian mentioned, glob does not return image objects... but also:

As it is right now, the script assumes the images in the folder are all the same size and shape. This is not often a safe assumption to make.

So for both of those reasons, you'll need to open the images before you can determine their size. Once you open it you should set the width, and scale the images to that width so there is no empty space.

Also, you didn't set miniature_filename anywhere in the script.